# Inverse limits of perfect groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is every group isomorphic to an inverse limit (that is, projective limit) of perfect groups?

I guess, the answer is no. In that case: Is there a characterization of the groups that are isomorphic to inverse limits of perfect groups?

Comment: What do you think of a group with 2 elements?

Comment: I haven't thought about the group with 2 elements. Do you say that it is not an inverse limit of perfect groups?

Comment: OK, it's possibly more subtle than I thought (since I usually use projective limits that are filtering and/or made of surjections). Indeed an intersection of subgroups in a larger group is a projective limit. For instance, a cyclic group of order 3 is the intersection of all standard copies of $\mathrm{Alt}_5$ containing it inside $\mathrm{Alt}_6$. This realizes it as a projective limit, if you confirm that you're not making any assumption such as filtering.

Comment: Actually, any group is an intersection of two perfect groups in a larger group. Namely, fix $G$, and embed it into a perfect group $P$ (e.g., a symmetric group). Consider the "double" amalgam $P\ast_G P$. Then $G$ is the intersection of the two copies of $P$. This realizes $G$ as a projective limit of the system $P\to P\ast_G P\leftarrow P$ of perfect groups.

Comment: It was not clear to me that every group is an intersection of two perfect groups, which seems like a useful fact to know. About the projective limits, I meant projective systems indexed over a directed set, for example sequential systems like $\ldots G_3\to G_2\to G_1$. But I guess one can also ask the question for arbitrary (co)filtered limits.

Comment: Unlike what I initially thought, groups with 2 elements are not trivial counterexamples, even in the filtering case! I thus posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

> Every group is isomorphic to a filtering projective limit of a sequence of perfect groups.

Start from a group $G$ and embed it into a perfect group $P$ (e.g., a symmetric group).

Consider the group $H$ obtained by amalgamating countably many copies $P_n$ of $P$ over $G$. Then $H$ is perfect. Let $H_n$ be the subgroup generated by $\bigcup_{k\ge n}P_k$; it is isomorphic to $H$ and also perfect. The decreasing intersection of the $H_n$ is reduced to $G$. Hence $G$ is an filtering projective limit of perfect groups.

(This can sound a bit surprising, since one mostly works with projective limits of surjections, in which case many groups cannot be obtained.)

Comment: PS: Of course we often work with (filtering) projective limits of injections, namely (decreasing) intersections... it's just that we usually don't need name them in this way.